# Foreign words reborrowed back into English

Tags: terminology, loanwords

Wikipedia mentions several English words that have been [reborrowed from Japanese](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gairaigo#Reborrowings_from_Japanese):

- *Anime* comes from *animation* and has been reborrowed into English to mean Japanese-style animation.
- *Puroresu* comes from *professional wrestling* and is a term for Japanese-style professional wrestling.
- *Kosupure* comes from *cosplay* (an abbreviation of *costume play*) and refers to the practice of dressing in costumes of anime and video game characters.

Do you know other examples of word reborrowings from Japanese or other languages back into English, or vice versa?

Comment: I've never heard "puroresu", and I always say "cosplay" if I mean cosplay. :P

Comment: Could someone with enough reputation please mark this question as a community wiki?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**From the French**

- *paquebot*, comes from the English *packet-boat* [in 1641](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/paquebot), use to mean *mailboat*, but now is used to describe a *ship, liner*, was reborrowed with the meaning mailboat [in 1894](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/paquebot#Etymology).
- *redingote*, comes from the English *riding-coat* [in 1725](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/redingote), reborrowed in English and means "A long coat or greatcoat, originally for men but now often for women". ([Source](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/redingote))

Answer (score 3):

The only one that springs immediately to mind is "Freeter," a contraction of *free* + *arbeiter*. This reborrowed mish-mash of English and German means a young adult who lives on a series or raft of part-time or casual jobs rather than traditional full-time, long-term employment.

A near-miss is "Rickshaw." This is a contraction and anglicisation of "Jin-riki-sha," a Japanese word for a western invention.

By the way, I would say that, as a re-borrowing, "cosplay" comes from "kosupure" rather than the other way around :-)

Comment: You are right about _cosplay_.  The English phrase _costume play_ became a loan word _kosuchūmu-purē_ in Japanese and acquired a new meaning, was shortened to _kosupure_ (1982), and was reborrowed in English as _cosplay_ (1993).  The years are from the Oxford English Dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

As I've said in another question, "karaoke" half-qualifies, as the second half of it is "okesutora" = "orchestra".