# What do we call English transliterations re-transliterated into English?

Tags: obscure-terms

**Anime** is an an abbreviation of `animation` transliterated into Japanese and then back into English (It could also be argued that it is a loan word, but for the sake of my point here we don't need to discuss this).

- how do we classify English words that have been transliterated into another language and then transliterated back into English?

(Perhaps this phoenomonon doesn't even exist, like I imagine it does.)

Comment: I am not sure that ***Anime*** is a perfect example of what you mean: 
c. 1985, Japanese for "animation," a term that seems to have arisen in the 1970s, apparently based on French animé "animated, lively, roused," ***from the same root as English animate (adj.)***.  Probably taken into Japanese from a phrase such as dessin animé "cartoon," literally "animated design," with the adjective abstracted or mistaken, due to its position, as a noun. http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=anime+&searchmode=none

Comment: @Josh: that supports this answer here... perhaps it should not be so downvoted? [Why is anime not spelt phonetically?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/284199/why-is-anime-not-spelt-phonetically)

Comment: The question has not been downvoted  as far as I can see.,

Comment: @Josh61: I was talking about Ricky's answer.

Comment: See also: [linguistics.se]

Comment: Please show some homework

Comment: I think you'd call it "yet-another-needless-word-for-an-obscure-concept-that-no-one-really-cares-about".

Comment: @HotLicks how do you spell that?

Comment: Are you thinking of something like _baikingu_, which is the transliteration of _viking_ into Japanese. In Japan, the word was adopted for _buffet_, and now baikingu is sometimes used in English to mean brunch.

Comment: @DKrueger great. Exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps [reborrowing](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/reborrowing):

> (linguistics) A word taken back from another language, or the process involved in this. Such words may have changed in meaning or form.

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reborrowing) for the term has examples.

There are also more examples in this question:
 [Foreign words reborrowed back into English](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6133/foreign-words-reborrowed-back-into-english)